# sails.js model reference error

Tags: mongodb, cron, sails.js

I am studying Sails.js and I have a question.
I made a model object using "sails generate model site" command.
and I made init.js file in config directory for my cronjob.
everytime system launched, cronjob starts from this init.js.

this is init.js

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    sails = require('sails'),
    async = require('async');

exports.initSite = function () {
    'use strict';
    sails.log.debug('init method start!');
    async.waterfall([
        function (callback) {
            Site.find().exec(function (err, sites) {
                if (err) {
                    callback(err);
                }

                if (sites) {

                    async.forEachSeries(sites,
                        function (siteData, callback2) {
                            siteData.remove(function (err) {
                                if (err) {
                                    callback(err);
                                }
                                callback2();
                            });
                        }, function (err) {
                            if (err) {
                                callback(err);
                            }
                            callback();
                        });
                } else {
                    callback();
                }
            });
        },
        function (callback) {
            var jsonData = fs.readFile('./urls.json', 'utf8', function (err, datas) {
                if (err) {
                    callback(err);
                }
                callback(null, datas);
            });
        },
        function (datas, callback) {
            var urls = JSON.parse(datas);
            for (var key in urls) {
                var value = urls[key];
                var site = new Site({
                    siteId: value.id,
                    name: value.name,
                    url: value.url,
                    category: value.category
                });
                site.save(function(err){
                    if (err) {
                        callback(err);
                    }
                });
            }
            callback();
        }
    ],function(err){
        if (err) {
            sails.log.error('ERROR！');
        }
        sails.log.info('INIT OK');
    });
};
```

and I read this init.js from app.js like this.

in app.js

```
require(__dirname + '/config/init').initSite();
```

but everytime I launch application, console messages says ReferenceError: Site is not defined.

I don't know why init.js can't read 'Site (model object)'.

your advice is very thankful for me.

(sorry for my bad english.... ;_;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sailsjs does not load your models until it has been "lifted". You need to run sails lift first from within the directory that your app.js file has been defined, then you can run this chron job. After sails loads, all your models will be exposed as globals. The code in init.js should be called from app.js after sails lifts.

Comment: thank you for your help aclave1. I solved this problem. I changed my code that initSite() in bootstrap.js. and cronjob works.

Answer (score 1):

This is based on the discussion about the above topic, so it's not exactly a "cron job" but it can be executed like one and also have access to all the nice features that Sails.js provides, including models.

You can use **node-schedule**.

So this is what i did.

1. Install node-schedule

```
npm install –save node-schedule
```

2. Create a crontab file in config/crontab.js

Paste this code in the crontab.js. What i am doing here is creating a method where i require my cronjob, finally i append the method to the jsonArray, so the config/bootstrap.js will execute the file.

```
module.exports.crontab = {

/*
* The asterisks in the key are equivalent to the
* schedule setting in crontab, i.e.
* minute hour day month day-of-week year
* so in the example below it will run every minute
*/

crons:function()
{
var jsonArray = [];
jsonArray.push({interval:’*/1 * * * * * ‘,method:’mytest’});

// add more cronjobs if you want like below
// but dont forget to add a new method…
//jsonArray.push({interval:’*/1 * * * * * ‘,method:’anothertest’});
return jsonArray;

},

// declare the method mytest
// and add it in the crons function
mytest: function(){
require(‘../crontab/mytest.js’).run();

}

/*
anothertest:function(){
require(‘../crontab/anothertest.js’).run();
}
*/

};
```

3. Open your config/bootstrap.js and add this code

```
module.exports.bootstrap = function(cb) {

_.extend(sails.hooks.http.app.locals, sails.config.http.locals);

// add the lines from here
// bootstrapping all the cronjobs in the crontab folder
var schedule = require(‘node-schedule’);
sails.config.crontab.crons().forEach(function(item){
schedule.scheduleJob(item.interval,sails.config.crontab[item.method]);
});

// It’s very important to trigger this callback method when you are finished
// with the bootstrap! (otherwise your server will never lift, since it’s waiting on the bootstrap)
cb();
};
```

Finally run sails l and you should see a message running every minute.